# can i use an indicator Constraint with Min/Max Constraint in Gurobi?

Tags: python, gurobi

i've the following model for Gurobi:

```
m = Model()
x = {}
    for k in range(K):
        for i in range(V):
            for j in range(V):
                if i != j:
                    x[k,i,j] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x(%s,%s,%s)"%(k,i,j))
a = {}
    for k in range(K):
        for i in range(V):
            a[k,i] = m.addVar(ub=25, vtype= GRB.INTEGER, name= "a(%s,%s)"%(k,i))
```

and i'm trying to write a constraint using the indicator Constraint with Min/Max Constraint like this:

```
m.addConstrs((x[k,i,j] == 1) >> (a[k,j] == max_((a[k,i] + 5), 15)) for k in range(K) for i in range(V) for j in range(1,V) if i!=j)
```

but i end up getting this Error:

```
  File "model.pxi", line 3070, in gurobipy.Model.addConstrs
  File "model.pxi", line 2951, in gurobipy.Model.addConstr
  File "model.pxi", line 3592, in gurobipy.Model.addGenConstrIndicator
  File "linexpr.pxi", line 461, in gurobipy.LinExpr.__sub__
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'GenExpr'
```

i've also tried a different variants to write this constraint like:

```
for k in range(K):
        for i in range(V):
            for j in range(1,V):
                if i!=j:
                    m.addConstr((x[k,i,j] == 1) >> ((a[k,j]) == max_((a[k,i] + 5), 15), "tww(%s)"%(i))
          #or
                    m.addGenConstrIndicator(x[k,i,j], True, a[k,j], GRB.EQUAL, max_((a[k,i] + 5), 15))
```

but also end up getting the same error as before or this one:

```
m.addGenConstrIndicator(x[k,i,j], True, a[k,j], GRB.EQUAL, max_((a[k,i] + 5), 15))
  File "model.pxi", line 3588, in gurobipy.Model.addGenConstrIndicator
gurobipy.GurobiError: Invalid rhs argument for general constraint of indicator type
```

is there something wrong that i'm doing or it just can't be done this way?

any help will be appreciated

Comment: This is answered here: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360056450492

Comment: i saw the comment on the Gurobi support just 30 minutes ago and i wanted to write that hier but you were faster :)
thank you for your comment.